# Files connect - unknown error

Tags: integration, office-365

I am trying to integrate Office 365 (trial Edition) onedrive with salesforce using files connect.And it is giving me "**An unknown error occurred while accessing Files Connect**".

here is what I am trying:

- Creating permission set to enable Files connect cloud. Assigning it
  to the user.
- Creating temp Auth. provider in SF.
- Creating an    App,Generating Consumer client and Secret in Office
  365
- Updating consumer clent Id and Secret in Auth. provider in SF.
- Updating app to    grant CRED permissions for files in Office 365.
- Creating external    data source followed by "Validate and Sync"
  Click.
- updating    permission set to allow external data source access.

After these steps, I go to Files tab. I see the link to One Drive. I go ahead and click the link, follow the step for first time authentication.

Authentication Successfull. I Go head and click the onedrive link again to access my files but it errors out.

I have no clue where I am missing. But here are my **assumptions**.

- Authentication was not proper.
- Site Url is not proper in external object:

if Below is my URL to site content,
*https://[company-name]/personal/[palceholder]/_layouts/15/onedrive.aspx?AjaxDelta=1*
then
*https://[company-name]/personal/[palceholder]* is my site URL value in External data soure.

- trial org does not allow integration.

I did try creating a tab for my external object and I could find records with link to my files and folders.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Exactly the same issue with a SharePoint Online account...(and OneDrive has pretty much the same architecture) : everything's OK till I try to access my files.

In Chatter > Files, I get an "unknown error", and no results from the global Salesforce search. And it's a production server, so it doesn't come from trial org... And I'm a Salesforce admin AND SharePoint admin.

Might be a problem within Files Connect application, there was already a patch last month, and it looks like the problem is still there: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008d9lAAA

Comment: Ya Seems like the bug has been fixed..I am now able to see my file from One Drive.